# VHDL and Verilog not dependent on technology?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

When designing something(for example CPU) in VHDL or Verilog and the design is completed, is design limited to a certant manufacturing process(14nm) or it can work on any(10,7,5,3nm) process that is currently available?

Comment: No guarantee. I could be that the design was made with a specific primitives and their timing constraints in mind. You need to reevaluate your whole design. That's for instance why CPU producers need so much time to switch technologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a hardware description language and thus technology independent. Both support technology specifics by instantiation of technology primitives.

Comment: It should be, but in my experience primitives are instantiated in the VHDL code, which depend on certain technology supplier libraries. You cannot assume that if code works with the library written for process x, it will automatically work the same for the library written for process y.

Comment: That's why my answer has 2 sentences :)